# Computing the average of numbers with MPI_Reduce

Tags: c, mpi

I'm trying to compute the average of 1000 numbers distributed across processes, using `MPI_reduce()`. Unfortunately, so far, my code only gives zero instead of the expected answer (the arithmetic mean of the numbers).

What did I do wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mpi.h>
#include <assert.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int world_rank, world_size, int_size, i ;
    int avg, rand_nums,n , sub_avg, startval, endval, *sub_rand_nums, *sub_avgs, N=1000 ;
    MPI_Init( &argc , &argv );
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD , &world_size);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD , &world_rank);
    startval = N * world_rank/world_size + 1;
    endval = N * (world_rank+1) / world_size;

    n = N / world_size;

    // Sum the numbers locally
    int local_sum = 0;

    for (i = startval; i <= endval; i++) {
        local_sum = local_sum+i;
    }

    // Print the random numbers on each process
    printf("Local sum for process %d - %f, avg = %f\n",
            world_rank, local_sum, local_sum / n);

    // Reduce all of the local sums into the global sum
    int global_sum=0;
    MPI_Reduce(&local_sum, &global_sum, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_SUM, 0,
               MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    // Print the result
    if (world_rank == 0) {
        printf("Total sum = %f, avg = %f\n", global_sum,
        global_sum / N);
    }

    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    MPI_Finalize();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem has actually nothing to do with MPI, but rather with C and `printf()`: just look at what a gcc gives as warning while trying to compile your code:

```
$ mpicc mean.c 
mean.c: In function ‘main’:
mean.c:26:13: warning: format ‘%f’ expects argument of type ‘double’, but argument 3 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
             world_rank, local_sum, local_sum / n);
             ^
mean.c:26:13: warning: format ‘%f’ expects argument of type ‘double’, but argument 4 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
mean.c:36:9: warning: format ‘%f’ expects argument of type ‘double’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
         global_sum / N);
         ^
mean.c:36:9: warning: format ‘%f’ expects argument of type ‘double’, but argument 3 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
```

From there, understanding the issue is trivial. Changing

```
printf("Local sum for process %d - %f, avg = %f\n",
        world_rank, local_sum, local_sum / n);
...
printf("Total sum = %f, avg = %f\n", global_sum,
       gobal_sum / N);
```

into

```
printf("Local sum for process %d - %d, avg = %f\n",
        world_rank, local_sum, local_sum * 1. / n);
...
printf("Total sum = %d, avg = %f\n", global_sum,
       gobal_sum / 1. * N);
```

makes the code to print what you expected...

Comment: thank you so much for your response and time. it was a great help.